# Meteor Run Error - 'Telescope'

Tags: meteor, meteorite

After I installed meteor and meteorite, tried to run Meteor and this error is thrown>

```
MacBook:telescope thanki$ sudo mrt

Stand back while Meteorite does its thing

Done installing smart packages

Ok, everything's ready. Here comes Meteor!

[[[[[ ~/Telescope ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.     
=> Errors prevented startup:

While building package `momentjs`:
error: File not found: moment/min/moment.min.js
error: File not found: moment/min/langs.min.js

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

---

Any fixes/suggestions?

Thanks much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing momentjs and adding moment, instead.

> mrt remove momentjs
>   mrt add moment

Noticed you need sudo (me too).

> sudo mrt remove momentjs
>   sudo mrt add moment

Comment: Thank you, Randell. Worked liked a charm. :)
Cheers!